# Basic C pointer declaration and pointer variable I'm confused over

Tags: c, pointers

```
int x = 2; int y = 3; int z[9];
```

Declare three int variable

```
int *ptr;
```

ptr is an int pointer (ptr points to int)

```
ptr = &x;
```

ptr points to x (Assigns the address of x to the variable ptr)

```
y = *ptr
```

y=2 dereferensing (Assigns the objects or contents or wathever ptr points at to the y)

```
*ptr = 1;
```

x=1 assgin new value or content to that address that ptr points to.

```
 ptr = &z[5]
```

ptr now points to z[5]

```
double update(char*)
```

Q1: Are my comments under each expression correct?

Q2:I understand that the function `update` has value of double and the argument is a char pointer 
but what happened with the char pointer variable 
there is only one `char*` no pointer variable 
how this work?

Comment: `int z = z[9];`...what's that?

Comment: `int z = z[9];` makes no sense

Comment: Oh sorry typo it should be `int z[9]`

Comment: Also this one `double *ptr update(char*)`

Comment: `double *ptr update(char*)` should be a syntax error...

Comment: All comments are ok for me. The function declaration should be `double* update(char* argument_name)` (If the pointer thing must be in the return type). Otherwise `double update(char* argument_name)`.

Comment: "what happened with the char pointer variable?" We won't know that unless you show us.

Comment: Even after the correction, I don't understand what you're trying to ask in Q2.

Comment: What is your **specific** problem? We are not a tutoring site. All your question will be answered by a C book.

Comment: Are you asking how to manipulate the passed argument? If yes, then you need to name the variable in that function,

Comment: @Olaf why there is no pointer variable in the function argument?

Comment: Oh, wait, I think I understand.  You're asking about the fact that in the declaration of function `update`, no *name* is given for the function parameter.  That's fine in a declaration of the function that does not accompany the function body, as the parameter name does not matter in such a context.  In the function *definition*, on the other hand, (where the function body is provided) a name must be provided for each parameter.

Comment: Just in case I was not clear: **read a C book and learn the language**. Particular questions will not give you the whole picture you need.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the general sentiment in the question's comments: **read a C book and learn the language before using StackOverflow**. Regardless, I'll try to answer your doubts.

---

[cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) is a great tool to translate C declaration syntax to english.

Example:

```
double update(char*);
```

will print:

```
declare update as function (pointer to char) returning double
```

---

Q1:  yes.

Q2: I assume you're confused by the fact that `char*` has no "name". Well, it is not required for a function parameter to have a name - only the type is enough.

```
double update(char*);
double update(char* a);
double update(char* hello);
```

The above declarations are equivalent.

If you want to refer to the parameter in the definition, then you obviously need a name:

```
double update(char* a)
{
    something(a);
}
```